# Need to get the Values of the altitude or Zoom level in MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a MapKit based application. I need a clarification that, it is possible to get the altitude or Zoom level of the mapView when we zoom in/out in the Map.Because based on that I need to call some events. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe how much area is shown in your mapView by inspecting the `region` property.

```
map.region.span.latitudeDelta
```

gives the current height of the map in degrees of latitude.  Latitude degrees are about 69 miles (or 111 kilometers).

```
map.region.span.longitudeDelta
```

will give you the width of the map in longitude degrees, but be aware that longitude lines are not parallel and the extent will vary based on the distance from the equator.  Much easier IMO to just deal with the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will go through as you suggested.